# How do I select an element if it exist in xml document

Tags: xml, xslt

**XML document**

```
<Case>
  <CaseParty>
    <Address>
      <AddressLine1>Testing</AddressLine1>
    </Address>
  </CaseParty>
</Case>
```

The problem is that sometimes the `<AddressLine1>Testing</AddressLine1>` element is not found in the path above. Instead it is found in the following path

```
<Party>
   <Address>
     <AddressLine1>Testing</AddressLine1>
   </Address>
</Party>
```

I would like to display `<AddressLine1>Testing</AddressLine1>`

If no element is found in `<CaseParty>`for the address I would like to use the following path
`<Address/AddressLine1>`

How do I do this?

My xslt code is only working if the element for addressline1 is found in `Party/Address/AddressLine1` but not when the element is only under `Case/CaseParty/Address/AddressLine1`

```
<Address>
    <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine1"/>
</Address>
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what the problem is.

Comment: Kinda hard to answer without knowing what the context is. Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional expression.

```
<Address>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/Case/CaseParty/Address/AddressLine1">
            <xsl:value-of select="/Case/CaseParty/Address/AddressLine1"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Party/Address/AddressLine1">
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</Address>
```

The choose block first checks if *AddressLine1* exists at */Case/CaseParty/Address/AddressLine1*, and if it does selects it.  Otherwise, it selects it from the other path.